# Symfony 3 Create validator from builder and UniqueEntity contraint

Tags: php, symfony, validation, doctrine-orm

I try to use validator in a service manage as an handler with [SimpleBus/MessageBus](https://github.com/SimpleBus/MessageBus)

I create my validator like this:

```
$this->validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
            ->addYamlMapping(__DIR__.'/../../Resources/config/validation/Directory.Person.yml')
            ->getValidator();
```

My Directory.Person.yml:

```
I360\DomainBundle\Entity\Directory\Person:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [gender, type]
            ignoreNull: false
    properties:
        lastname:
            - NotBlank: ~
        gender:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

And finally i validate my entity with:

```
$this->validator->validate($contact);` ($contact is an instance of Person class)
```

Validation of properties works but validation of UniqueEntity throws this error;

> Attempted to load class "doctrine.orm.validator.unique" from the
>   global namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement?"

I also try with annotions, the same problem occurs.
This problem doesn't occur when i try to validate my entiy in a controller.

Does i miss something? Or do something wrong?

Comment: have you put the use in top of your file ?

Comment: doctrine.orm.validator.unique is not a class. It's a key in orm.xml from Doctrine Bundle which referer to the class "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity" which i already try to put in use list of my file without success

Comment: The bridge is only going to work inside of an actual Symfony framework application.  Not sure why you are getting the class not found message though it would help if your posted yaml file matched your posted error message.  But even once you get past this you will still have to configure and inject an entity manager.

Comment: Which yaml file do you want? I must inject an Entiy manager inside the validator?

Comment: Any luck with this error?

Comment: No, i finally refactor my code to avoid this error ...